# Primeng v12.x how to add css to animate p-component-overlay-leave which is not happening automatically

Tags: css-animations, primeng, angular11

I am new to animations in css.

I have just upgraded primeng version to v12 to my angular application 11.
I am using primeng sidebar. the sidebar after closed, the overlay is not disappearing.
Can see p-component-overlay-leave classes is added to the overlay but since there is no corresponding animation css available it is not disappearing. can anyone show me how to add this so the overlay disappears after the sidebar is closed.

css added for overlay enter:

```
.p-component-overlay-enter {
    animation: p-component-overlay-enter-animation 150ms forwards;
    animation-duration: 150ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: p-component-overlay-enter-animation;
}
```

trying to add the following but not sure how to add the respective css:

```
.p-component-overlay-leave {
    animation: p-component-overlay-leave-animation 150ms forward;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the following and it worked

```
.p-component-overlay-leave {
    animation: p-component-overlay-leave-animation 150ms forwards;
}

@keyframes p-component-overlay-leave-animation {
    from {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    to {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
}
```